# We've hit some [traffic] and need to merge

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

[traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/traffic) seems to be the same tag as [network-traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-traffic) (some questions even use both at once).

Should they be merged & synonymised?

---

Furthermore, there is also [traffic-filtering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/traffic-filtering) and [traffic-shaping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/traffic-shaping), I don't know whether these should stay separate or not, but if so, perhaps they could also be renamed to

- [network-traffic-filtering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-traffic-filtering) (25 characters) and
- [network-traffic-shaping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-traffic-shaping) (23 characters)

to continue the [network-*] trend. Thoughts?

Comment: If they were defined they would be different, but because traffic and network-traffic are both undefined yes they are technically the same. I don't see any real difference between traffic and network traffic except for cars on the road.

Comment: @JCTechie But that's just it: what other type of traffic would be relevant to Super User? I went through all the [traffic] questions and couldn't see any that weren't talking about networks

Comment: Meh, anyone with ton of work and the desire to procrastinate for half an hour can retag those... and possible close vote them all.

Comment: @Braiam - The synonym suggestion is primarily to stop the tag being recreated in future (and also to act as a signpost to the correct tag). I understand how quickly they could be retagged :-). Plus synonymisation would take 2 seconds and wouldn't needlessly bump 78 questions (flooding the main page in the process).

Comment: I doubt that it will get recreated. It has only 2 questions in the last 30 days, one of them in the last 7 days. Only 9 of the latest 50 askers had the privilege to create tags, all of them haven't used the tag again.

Comment: @JCTechie: Other communications traffic (queues), or even printer queues.  However, network traffic is probably most common.

Comment: @TOOGAM That's a good point.

Comment: @Robotnik Well, consider that the only traffic related to SU is data traffic, because nothing else should apply. How does data travel? over the wire of course. What wires are we dealing with? Most commonly, cables like USB cables that connect devices directly to each other, or network cables. And how often is SU gonna be bombarded with data traffic questions related to the cable(s) that directly connects someone's laptop to their printer?

Comment: Not to sure, but that may be your point anyway

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking to check what differences currently exist, suspecting there might not be any.  However, based on [@Robotnik's comment](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11483/weve-hit-some-traffic-and-need-to-merge#comment-30245), we already have an answer, so we needn't go out of our way to check on that.

Based on Robotnik's conclusion, I'd say kill the more ambiguous "traffic" tag.

There are forms of traffic filtering other than just shaping, so those tags are appropriate to remain different from each other.  (Shaping is about changing the existing traffic.  Filtering can often involve just dropping packets.)